# Getting error when multiple results passing to view in asp.net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use asp.net mvc 5 and EF 6 .I have following code in my controller

```
 var resultOne = stats.GetPlayerStatsByParam(year, modeOne); //first
  ViewData["more"] = stats.GetTeamStatsID(year); //second
 return View("StatsNew", resultOne.ToList());
```

I am able to display result in view using `"resultOne"`. Now I want to pass another data to same view using `ViewData[]`. its a stored procedure and the result is paasing to `"ViewData["more"]"`.

I have done following code for "ViewData["more"]" in View page 
But I am getting an error saying that 'object reference not set'

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["more"] as @List<demo.GetTeamStatsID_Result>)
{
  @item.Pld;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just using a view model containing properties for both results (and pass that view model to the view)

Comment: I use database first approach and stored procedure to get data

Comment: Great - but that has nothing to do with it! Create a view model containing 2 properties - one for whatever your `stats.GetPlayerStatsByParam(year, modeOne);` and another for whatever your `stats.GetTeamStatsID(year);` returns (and is your model really named `GetTeamStatsID_Result`?)

Comment: okay, But this GetTeamStatsID(year) returns data from 2 different table (it has relationship)and Then I pass to controller. Its not an issue when using in viewmodel ?

Comment: Always use a view model. And it makes no difference if the data comes from 1000 tables - your view model will contain a property `public List<GetTeamStatsID_Result> TeamStats { get; set; }` and you will set that property based on the result of you query (and ditto for the other query)

Answer (score 0):

Use a viewmodel and extend it by the data coming from `stats.GetTeamStatsID(year);`

Do not use ViewBag or ViewData if not necessary for some reason (which I can´t imagine right now)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have already pointed out, build a ViewModel class, that wraps everthing you need:

```
//I am using fake types here, sinceI don't know your model classes
//substitute accordingly!
public class MyViewModel
{
   public PlayerStatsType PlayerStats { get; set;}
   public List<demo.GetTeamStatsID_Result> Teams { get; set;}
}
```

Then in your action method:

```
var vm = new MyViewModel();
vm.PlayerStats = stats.GetPlayerStatsByParam(year, modeOne); //first
vm.TeamId = stats.GetTeamStatsID(year); //second
return View("StatsNew", vm);
```

Amend the model declaration in your view:

```
@model Namespace.Models.MyViewModel //again use namespace for your vm class
```

Now you can access both properties from your model:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Teams)
{
   @item.Pld;
}
```